# How to apply a formula to an entire column in EPPLUS Core?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'd like to apply a formula to an entire column, even if I insert a new row, I need all cells from a certain column to have the formula in EPPLUS Core.

For exemple, I would like to apply a formula to the column `C`.

So every cell in column `C` (`C1,C2,...,C999999`) will have the formula

Comment: *I'd like to apply a formula to an entire column*. Ok that is great. Please go ahead.

Comment: What is the problem ? I just want to know if there is anyway to apply a formula to all cells of a column. We can do it with styles, but I didn't managed to find if there is a way to do it with formula using EPPLUS.

Comment: @galiolio, what have you tried? and what do you mean by "apply a formula to entire column" give us an example

Comment: For exemple, for the column C, I want all cells in this column containing my formula.

Answer (score 2):

Here I wanted to concatenate Column 'A' and Column 'C' and put the result in column 'B' for each row. example : formula of B10 = CONCATENATE(A10,C10)

This can be easily done with

```
worksheet.Cells[1, 2, 100, 2].FormulaR1C1 = "CONCATENATE( RC[-1] , RC[1] )";
```

Here `Cells[1, 2, 100, 2]` means starting from row 1 in column 2 to row 100 in column 2. 
`RC[-1]` means one cell to left, `RC[1]` means one cell to right.

Answer (score 0):

Define your range as a Table and then write your formula in that table.

Now even if you try to insert a new row, the table property will automatically insert the formula into that newly inserted cell of that table in that column.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: So is there a way to define an entire column as a table with EEPLUS ?